# How do I show and hide a div in a MERN app?

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, toggle

I'm trying to create a Portfolio page using React. I want to be able to display a reusable modal upon a button click that displays the skills used in the apps I have created.

So far I've created a couple of dummy divs with generic info in them. However, when I click on the button, nothing happens at all. In my modal file, I have a constructor with state and modalHandler function bound.

My Modal.js file:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import "./modal.css";

    class Modal extends Component {
         constructor(props)  {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                modalToggle: true
            };
            this.modalHandler = this.modalHandler.bind(this)
        }

        modalHandler = (e) => {
            e.preventDefault(); //i added this to prevent the default 
    behavior
            const modalToggle = this.state;
            this.setState({
              modalToggle: !modalToggle
            })
          }      

        render()    {
            return(
                <div class="modalContent">
                    {this.props.children}
                </div> 
            );
        }
    }

    export default Modal;
```

my modal.css file:

```
    .modalContent   {
        background: black;
        color: #ffef96;
        border: #ffef96 1px solid;
    }
```

my Portfolio.js file:

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import "./portfolio.css";
    import dadirri from "../../images/rsz_1dadirri.png";
    import Modal from "../../components/Modal/Modal";

    class Portfolio extends Component   {
        render() {

        return (
            <div className="container">
                <div class="row pagecolor">
                    <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl- 
    12">
                    <h4 class="page-header" style={{marginTop: "10px", 
    paddingLeft: "70px", paddingRight: "60px"}}>Portfolio<hr/></h4>
                        <div class="row" id="apps">
                            <div classname="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-2 
    col-xl-2">
                                <div class="card bg-dark mb-3" style={{width: 
    "19rem", boxShadow: "10px 10px 2px black", transform: 
    "translateY(4px)"}}>
                                <img src={dadirri} class="card-img-top-fluid" 
    alt="dadirri" style={{paddingBottom: "25px"}}></img>
                                    <div class="card-body">
                                        <button onClick={this.modalHandler} 
    style={{color: "#ffef96", background: "black", fontSize: "24px", width: 
    "60%", height: "50px", border: "#ffef96 solid 1px", fontFamily: 
    "'Cinzel', serif"}}>Dadirri</button>
                                        {this.setState.modalToggle && <Modal>
                                            <div style={{color:'#ffef96'}}>
                                            The Best Has Happened To ME
                                            </div>
                                        </Modal>} 
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body" style= 
    {{textDecoration: "underline"}}>
                                        <a 
    href="https://dadirri.herokuapp.com/" className="card- 
    link">Deployment</a><hr/>
                                        <a 
    href="https://github.com/jlevine84/Dadirri" className="card-link">Github 
    Repo</a>
                                    </div>
                                 </div>
                            </div>
```

No error messages surface in the console when I click on the button

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! There are quite a number of issues in your code that you have provided. Are you following a react tutorial? Have you read through the official "getting started" docs? https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Yes I was following a react tutorial on youtube. What issues do I have?

Comment: There are many. You are using `class` many times instead of `className`.. `classname` instead of `className`. you are trying to access a property on the `setState` method... you are trying to get state values on a component that doesn't have any state... the youtube video you are watching may not be very good. I would begin with the link I provided

Comment: I know about className. When I changed everything to className the page wouldn't compile so I left as is and it's rendering for some strange reason

Comment: Your code example is incomplete, missing closing tags for the JSX and closing brackets for the render method and Class block. Please

Comment: You are also trying to access state in the Portfolio component even though it has not state set. I'm guessing you want to pass down modalToggle as a prop to Portfolio from somewhere else. But I can't see where you introduce the Portofilio component to your app in your examples.

Comment: I imported the Modal component in the App.js file and am trying to use the modal on my portfolio page. Trying to figure this out in a MERN app is confusing

Comment: "Even when you count to a million you still need to start with the number one". I would stop your current MERN project and train on the React basics, then you will feel more comfortable and prepared to work on your portfolio again.

Comment: Well I've looked at the documentation all day. That's why I came here. I got the buttons and the modal divs rendered on the screen. Just trying to figure out how to hide said modal and show it on a button click

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out creating unique functions for each modal with their own onClick and onClose functions. Can't believe I pulled it off!. I'll post the link to my code when I'm done. Thank all you guys for your assistance!